# Using CSS to manipulate a SVG added with ::before pseudo-element?

Tags: css, svg, css-selectors

I replaced a checkbox button with SVG-image in a most common way:

```
[type="checkbox"] + label:before {
    content: url("data:image/svg+xml,<svg ...> ... </svg>");
    /* Some more styling */
}
```

Is there any way, i can target my SVG's path with CSS to change it's fill for example? Probably not, but...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot target, with a CSS selector, the contents of a `::before` pseudo-element, nor can you target elements in an embedded SVG document from within its host document — regardless of how it was embedded.